# WooCommerce Checkout Total Duplication Bug

Tags: woocommerce

Is there anyone that could help me with this duplication bug? It seems that the order total is duplicating on my woocommerce store checkout page. It is always showing the checkout total as it would be if the customer chose in store pickup even if they choose shipping as their option. I'm looking for a way to disable the elements circled in red on my checkout page.

I went to the template file in my wordpress backend, but am unsure how to edit this. I am using the Flatsome Child Theme for woocommerce.

[Element I need to remove is linked here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNjyu.png)

Answer (score -1):

Do you have a plugin for checkout page? if you don't know which plugin is affecting to checkout page you can try disable other plugins. Other way is you can try to adding custom css. For example:

```
.class-name{
  display:none;
    }
```

If the code doesn't work you can try this:

```
.class-name{
  display:none !important;
    }
```

Comment: Where in the custom CSS would I add this code?

Comment: [Step1:](https://prnt.sc/16m74n6)     [Step2:](https://prnt.sc/16m7cf4)                               
 [Step3:](https://prnt.sc/16m7nef)